# Model binding when using AJAX to insert a form

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Figured I should write my question at the top of the page since there is a crap load of code to follow.

I have an outer view model that contains a list of inner view models. When I click save on the Create page and it goes to the Create POST function `public ActionResult Create(DeviceTypeEntryViewModel model)` the outer model is filled however its list of inner view models is null.  What am I doing wrong?

The view models are:

```
public class DeviceTypeEntryViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<AttributeEntryViewModel> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeEntryViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Private { get; set; }
}
```

Create view that contains the Device Entry View:

```
@model ICMDB.ViewModels.DeviceTypeEntryViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ICMD - Create Device Type";
}

<h2>Create Device Type</h2>

<div class="form-div">
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        Html.RenderPartial("_DeviceTypeEntryPartial", Model);
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="form-button"/>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DeviceType"))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="form-button"/>
    }       
</div>
```

Device entry view partial:

```
@model ICMDB.ViewModels.DeviceTypeEntryViewModel

<fieldset>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type) </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
    </div>

    <div> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>

    <table id="AttributesTable" class="editor-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Private</th>
        </tr>

         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Attributes)
    </table>

    <input id="addAttributeButton" type="button" value="Add" 
     onclick="AddAttribute()" />
</fieldset>
```

Editor template for AttributeEntryViewModel:

```
@model ICMDB.ViewModels.AttributeEntryViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AttributePrivate)
    </td>
</tr>
```

AJAX calls to add attribute rows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddAttribute() {
        // and send it as AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddAttribute")',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                // when the AJAX succeeds add result to the table
                $('#AttributesTable').append(result);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Controller function on the other side of the AJAX call for adding:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAttribute()
{
   var model = new AttributeEntryViewModel();
   return PartialView("EditorTemplates/AttributeEntryViewModel", model);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you use AJAX to insert new entries to the table, input elements do not have the [proper naming](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) for the default model binder to bind them back. Inspect with FireBug and you will see that indexes of the collections are not respected. To achieve what you are trying I would recommend you the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).

Comment: Thanks @Darin, you seem to answer all my ASP..NET MVC questions! :D